# simple conditional expectation

Tags: probability

let $m$ be the lebesgue measure on $\Omega =[0,1]$. I'm trying to find the following conditional expectation (from this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540761756)):

$$E[\xi|\eta]$$

where $\xi(x)=2x^2$ and

$$\eta(x) = \begin{cases} 2 &\mbox{if } x \in[0,\frac{1}{2}) \\
x & \mbox{if } x \in [\frac{1}{2},1]. \end{cases}$$

Obviously the $E[\xi|\eta]$ will depend on the two intervals as $\eta$. I was able to show that $E[\xi|\eta]=\frac{1}{6}$ for $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2})$.
How can I tackle the other set?

Comment: I have the example from a book, see edited post. The claim the solution is $E[\xi|eta](x)=\frac{1}{6}\mathbf1_{x\in[0,\frac{1}{2})}+2x^2\mathbf1_{x\in [ \frac{1}{2},2]}$

Comment: Yes, I was too hasty (deleting my previous comment) and should have written $$E(\xi|\eta)=\frac16\mathbf 1_{\eta\lt1/2}+2\eta^2\mathbf 1_{\eta\geqslant1/2}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you explain how you got the answer?

Comment: Applying the definition of conditional expectation. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Did Since $\eta$ is not discrete here, I would use: $Z:=E[\xi|\eta]$ is the r.v. so that $Z$ is $\sigma(\eta)$ measurable and for every $A\in\sigma(\eta)$ we have $E[Z\mathbf1_A] = E[\xi\mathbf1_A]$ (I omit the integrability condition). If there is an easier way, I'm happy to hear that one.

Comment: This is the definition. If need be, the first condition can be rewritten as $E(\xi|\eta)=u(\eta)$ for some suitable measurable function $u$. If need be, the second condition can be rewritten as $E(\xi v(\eta))=E(u(\eta)v(\eta))$ for every measurable (bounded) test function $v$.